# Error when compiling unity at the build gradle project stage

Tags: java, c#, unity-game-engine, gradle, build.gradle

I am compiling a large unity project (24 gigabytes) for android. The whole compilation goes fine until the last stage of the build gradle project. Player settings: il2cpp, arm64. The error itself: **java.lang.illegalargumentexception: value (6702647363) > 0x00000000ffffffffl**. I don't understand at all what he's swearing at, please help! This is a 64k zip(apk) limit? Updated:
Probably my fears about the 64k limit have been confirmed, when the weight of the project changes, the error also changes. And if i generate obb, it will not help, since the obb file is 2gb+.
Unity: 2019.2.17f1 Full Stack of gradle:

> ```
> > org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task
> > ':packageDebug'.    at
> > org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter$3.accept(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:151)
> >     at
> > org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter$3.accept(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:148)
> >     at org.gradle.internal.Try$Failure.ifSuccessfulOrElse(Try.java:191)
> >     at
> > org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:141)
> >     at
> > org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveBeforeExecutionStateTaskExecuter.execute(ResolveBeforeExecutionStateTaskExecuter.java:75)
> >     at
> > org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:62)
> >     at
> > org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:108)
> >     at
> > org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveBeforeExecutionOutputsTaskExecuter.execute(ResolveBeforeExecutionOutputsTaskExecuter.java:67)
> >     at
> > org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveAfterPreviousExecutionStateTaskExecuter.execute(ResolveAfterPreviousExecutionStateTaskExecuter.java:46)
> >     at
> > org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.execute(CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.java:94)
> >     at
> > org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.FinalizePropertiesTaskExecuter.execute(FinalizePropertiesTaskExecuter.java:46)
> >     at
> > org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskExecutionModeExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskExecutionModeExecuter.java:95)
> >     at
> > org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:57)
> >     at
> > org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:56)
> >     at
> > org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.execute(CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.java:36)
> >     at
> > org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.executeTask(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:73)
> >     at
> > org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.call(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:52)
> >     at
> > org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.call(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:49)
> >     at
> > org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:416)
> >     at
> > org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:406)
> >     at
> > org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:165)
> >     at
> > org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:250)
> >     at
> > org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:158)
> >     at
> > org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.call(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:102)
> >     at
> > org.gradle.internal.operations.DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.call(DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.java:36)
> >     at
> > org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter.execute(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:49)
> >     at
> > org.gradle.execution.plan.LocalTaskNodeExecutor.execute(LocalTaskNodeExecutor.java:43)
> >     at
> > org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$InvokeNodeExecutorsAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:355)
> >     at
> > org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$InvokeNodeExecutorsAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:343)
> >     at
> > org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$BuildOperationAwareExecutionAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:336)
> >     at
> > org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$BuildOperationAwareExecutionAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:322)
> >     at
> > org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:134)
> >     at
> > org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:129)
> >     at
> > org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.execute(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:202)
> >     at
> > org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.executeNextNode(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:193)
> >     at
> > org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.run(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:129)
> >     at
> > org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:63)
> >     at
> > org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:46)
> >     at
> > org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:55)
> > Caused by: org.gradle.tooling.BuildException: 1 exception was raised
> > by workers: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException:
> > java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: value (6702599354) >
> > 0x00000000ffffffffL
> > 
> >     at
> > com.android.build.gradle.internal.scope.BuildElements$WorkersBasedScheduler$transform$2.call(BuildElements.kt:229)
> >     at
> > com.android.build.gradle.internal.scope.BuildElements$WorkersBasedScheduler$transform$2.call(BuildElements.kt:193)
> >     at
> > com.android.build.gradle.internal.scope.BuildElements$WorkersBasedScheduler.into(BuildElements.kt:202)
> >     at
> > com.android.build.gradle.internal.scope.BuildElementActionScheduler.into(BuildElementActionScheduler.kt:37)
> >     at
> > com.android.build.gradle.tasks.PackageAndroidArtifact.doFullTaskAction(PackageAndroidArtifact.java:428)
> >     at
> > com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.IncrementalTask.taskAction(IncrementalTask.java:106)
> >     at
> > java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native
> > Method)     at
> > java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
> >     at
> > java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
> >     at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:103)
> >     at
> > org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.IncrementalTaskInputsTaskAction.doExecute(IncrementalTaskInputsTaskAction.java:46)
> >     at
> > org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.execute(StandardTaskAction.java:41)
> >     at
> > org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AbstractIncrementalTaskAction.execute(AbstractIncrementalTaskAction.java:25)
> >     at
> > org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.execute(StandardTaskAction.java:28)
> >     at
> > org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter$5.run(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:404)
> >     at
> > org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:402)
> >     at
> > org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:394)
> >     at
> > org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:165)
> >     at
> > org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:250)
> >     at
> > org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:158)
> >     at
> > org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:92)
> >     at
> > org.gradle.internal.operations.DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.run(DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.java:31)
> >     at
> > org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeAction(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:393)
> >     at
> > org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:376)
> >     at
> > org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.access$200(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:80)
> >     at
> > org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter$TaskExecution.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:213)
> >     at
> > org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ExecuteStep.lambda$execute$0(ExecuteStep.java:32)
> >     at
> > org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ExecuteStep.execute(ExecuteStep.java:32)
> >     at
> > org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ExecuteStep.execute(ExecuteStep.java:26)
> >     at
> > org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CleanupOutputsStep.execute(CleanupOutputsStep.java:58)
> >     at
> > org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CleanupOutputsStep.execute(CleanupOutputsStep.java:35)
> >     at
> > org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ResolveInputChangesStep.execute(ResolveInputChangesStep.java:48)
> >     at
> > org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ResolveInputChangesStep.execute(ResolveInputChangesStep.java:33)
> >     at
> > org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CancelExecutionStep.execute(CancelExecutionStep.java:39)
> >     at
> > org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.TimeoutStep.executeWithoutTimeout(TimeoutStep.java:73)
> >     at
> > org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.TimeoutStep.execute(TimeoutStep.java:54)
> >     at
> > org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CatchExceptionStep.execute(CatchExceptionStep.java:35)
> >     at
> > org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CreateOutputsStep.execute(CreateOutputsStep.java:51)
> >     at
> > org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SnapshotOutputsStep.execute(SnapshotOutputsStep.java:45)
> >     at
> > org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SnapshotOutputsStep.execute(SnapshotOutputsStep.java:31)
> >     at
> > org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CacheStep.executeWithoutCache(CacheStep.java:201)
> >     at
> > org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CacheStep.execute(CacheStep.java:70)
> >     at
> > org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CacheStep.execute(CacheStep.java:45)
> >     at
> > org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.BroadcastChangingOutputsStep.execute(BroadcastChangingOutputsStep.java:49)
> >     at
> > org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.StoreSnapshotsStep.execute(StoreSnapshotsStep.java:43)
> >     at
> > org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.StoreSnapshotsStep.execute(StoreSnapshotsStep.java:32)
> >     at
> > org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.RecordOutputsStep.execute(RecordOutputsStep.java:38)
> >     at
> > org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.RecordOutputsStep.execute(RecordOutputsStep.java:24)
> >     at
> > org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipUpToDateStep.executeBecause(SkipUpToDateStep.java:96)
> >     at
> > org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipUpToDateStep.lambda$execute$0(SkipUpToDateStep.java:89)
> >     at
> > org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipUpToDateStep.execute(SkipUpToDateStep.java:54)
> >     at
> > org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipUpToDateStep.execute(SkipUpToDateStep.java:38)
> >     at
> > org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ResolveChangesStep.execute(ResolveChangesStep.java:77)
> >     at
> > org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ResolveChangesStep.execute(ResolveChangesStep.java:37)
> >     at
> > org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.legacy.MarkSnapshottingInputsFinishedStep.execute(MarkSnapshottingInputsFinishedStep.java:36)
> >     at
> > org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.legacy.MarkSnapshottingInputsFinishedStep.execute(MarkSnapshottingInputsFinishedStep.java:26)
> >     at
> > org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ResolveCachingStateStep.execute(ResolveCachingStateStep.java:90)
> >     at
> > org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ResolveCachingStateStep.execute(ResolveCachingStateStep.java:48)
> >     at
> > org.gradle.internal.execution.impl.DefaultWorkExecutor.execute(DefaultWorkExecutor.java:33)
> >     at
> > org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:120)
> >     ... 35 more Caused by:
> > com.android.ide.common.workers.WorkerExecutorException: 1 exception
> > was raised by workers: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException:
> > java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: value (6702599354) >
> > 0x00000000ffffffffL
> > 
> >     at
> > com.android.ide.common.workers.ExecutorServiceAdapter.await(ExecutorServiceAdapter.kt:62)
> >     at
> > com.android.build.gradle.internal.scope.BuildElements$WorkersBasedScheduler$transform$2.call(BuildElements.kt:227)
> >     ... 94 more Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException:
> > java.lang.IllegalArgumentException:
> > java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: value (6702599354) >
> > 0x00000000ffffffffL     at
> > com.android.ide.common.workers.ExecutorServiceAdapter.await(ExecutorServiceAdapter.kt:56)
> >     ... 95 more Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException:
> > java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: value (6702599354) >
> > 0x00000000ffffffffL     at
> > java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native
> > Method)     at
> > java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
> >     at
> > java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
> >     ... 96 more Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: value
> > (6702599354) > 0x00000000ffffffffL  at
> > com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkArgument(Preconditions.java:202)
> >     at
> > com.android.tools.build.apkzlib.zip.ZipField.write(ZipField.java:280)
> >     at
> > com.android.tools.build.apkzlib.zip.StoredEntry.writeData(StoredEntry.java:687)
> >     at
> > com.android.tools.build.apkzlib.zip.StoredEntry.toHeaderData(StoredEntry.java:666)
> >     at
> > com.android.tools.build.apkzlib.zip.ZFile.writeEntry(ZFile.java:1388)
> >     at
> > com.android.tools.build.apkzlib.zip.ZFile.writeAllFilesToZip(ZFile.java:1186)
> >     at com.android.tools.build.apkzlib.zip.ZFile.update(ZFile.java:1010)
> >     at com.android.tools.build.apkzlib.zip.ZFile.close(ZFile.java:1335)
> >     at
> > com.android.tools.build.apkzlib.zfile.ApkZFileCreator.close(ApkZFileCreator.java:170)
> >     at com.google.common.io.Closer.close(Closer.java:214)   at
> > com.android.builder.internal.packaging.IncrementalPackager.close(IncrementalPackager.java:332)
> >     at
> > com.android.build.gradle.tasks.PackageAndroidArtifact.doTask(PackageAndroidArtifact.java:828)
> >     at
> > com.android.build.gradle.tasks.PackageAndroidArtifact.access$100(PackageAndroidArtifact.java:115)
> >     at
> > com.android.build.gradle.tasks.PackageAndroidArtifact$FullActionSplitterRunnable.run(PackageAndroidArtifact.java:554)
> >     at
> > com.android.ide.common.workers.ExecutorServiceAdapter$submit$submission$1.run(ExecutorServiceAdapter.kt:40)
> ```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: The number is bigger than 32 bits.

Comment: @Voidsay I choose the android platform x64 (arm64), or is it not suitable?

Comment: as I understand it, this gradle Compiler error appears due to the fact that somehow the apk is generated 32bit and there is an overflow of some variable. I don't understand why it generates 32bit if arm64(64bit) is set in player settings. Maybe there is a hidden setting somewhere?

Comment: You should look into the full stacktrace. It should give you a better idea on where this is happening.

Comment: @Voidsay 
attached full stack to the question